Keycloak kerberos authentication error: cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
I'm trying to setup Keycloak SSO to my web-site using Kerberos authentication. I' using:

Keycloak 23.04 on Centos 9
Windows based Active Directory

I used this guide to set it up Kerberos Authentication in Keycloak for ZIC, but at the end I faced this problem:
 Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is /root/key2.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/server_dns@KERBEROS_REALM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
 principal is HTTP/server_dns@KERBEROS_REALM
 Will use keytab
 Commit Succeeded
 2024-05-21 10:10:36,396 WARN  [org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator] (executor-thread-184) SPNEGO login failed: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:716)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:439)
at org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator.authenticate(SPNEGOAuthenticator.java:69)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.authenticate(LDAPStorageProvider.java:757)
at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByCredential(UserStorageManager.java:153)
at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByCredential(UserCacheSession.java:551)
at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:88)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:445)
at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:271)
at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1028)
at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:885)
at org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:153)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:337)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.process(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:202)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildGet(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:113)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint$quarkusrestinvoker$buildGet_4b690b27439f19dd29733dc5fd4004f24de0adb6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
 Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:864)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:908)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(SpNegoContext.java:555)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:361)
at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:303)
at org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator.establishContext(SPNEGOAuthenticator.java:168)
at org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator$AcceptSecContext.run(SPNEGOAuthenticator.java:131)
at org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator$AcceptSecContext.run(SPNEGOAuthenticator.java:121)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
... 25 more
 Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP-REQ - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96

I already made a user and a keytab file for him with the following command
ktpass -princ HTTP/server_dns@KERBEROS_REALM -mapuser kerberos_user -pass mypassword -out key.keytab -crypto aes256-sha1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL.
User on local domain computer can get a token from domain controller via that keytab file by the following command kinit -kt keycloak.keytab HTTP/server_dns@KERBEROS_REALM. And the logs in domain controlles and packets that captured in wireshark says that audit success. But the keyclock does not authenticate and displays an error. At first i thougth that i use wrong encryption, not aes 256 that keycloak is complaining about. But when i use klist -etk keycloak.keytab to see the info about keytab file it says that aes 256 is the only encryption that is used:
Keytab name: FILE:keycloak.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal
---- ------------------- ------------------------------------------------------
  23 01/01/1970 03:00:00 HTTP/server_dns@KERBEROS_REALM (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)

Then I thought the problem was with KNVO and it doesn't match the user's msDS-KeyVersionNumber which is used for Kerberos authentication, but they match. After this I have no more ideas what could be causing this problem, so I just regenerated the keytab file with the -crypto all key, as many sites advise, but that didn’t help either.
Could you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks very much!

Your klist command says the file was keycloak.keytab, but your service's logs say it's looking for /root/key2.keytab. Are those the same?

@user1686 ,almost, keycloak.keytab is the file with the key -crypto aes256-sha1, and key2.keytab is the file with the key -crypto all, but the rest of the settings are the same.

And is the file readable by the system account that keycloak is running as? Normally /root isn't accessible by other accounts (and I'd hope keycloak is not running as root), so it's not the typical place for service configs.

Yes, I made keycloak the owner of this file. Here are his rights: -rw-r--r--. 1 keycloak keycloak        94 May 17 14:28  key2.keytab.

What about the permissions of the entire directory – does keycloak have +x on it? Does SELinux allow the service to reach into /root?

You were right, keycloak have no rights to read in this directory, thank you very much! Everything works now.
